# how to center a random background in a javascript

Tags: javascript, css, random, background, center

I've looked on stackoverflow for a background js. After trying some I found what I thought was exactly what I need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ChangeIt();
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var totalCount = 8;
function ChangeIt()
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.background = 'http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/image_background/'+num+'.jpg';
document.body.style.repeat = "contain";// Background repeat
}
</script>
```

However, the backgrounds don't center, you just see 'em on the top left corner. So I googled on the net  but... well idk anything about js, just a little few things. I'm helping a friend with his website and we're stuck on this. I'm just hoping someone with more knowledge than us can help by giving a look.

EDIT : Here's what i mean by "center" : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQhMV.png

Comment: what do you mean by centre? bg image applies to the whole background. See http://jsfiddle.net/3c8d91f0/

Comment: tnx for reply, well i mean exactly what i said, center the image
i hope you understand looking this : http://i.imgur.com/G3Z9epT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle that uses css instead of js for this, also I've added a `background-size` on body so the entire image is visible on all screen sizes, this is optional however - http://jsfiddle.net/dk329q1L/

Here's the css -

```
body {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /* Entire background image always stays in view */
}
```

Comment: wow, sounds good :D does it center the bg on both x,y axis ?
( what i mean : http://i.imgur.com/qoz58Yq.png )

Comment: yes, background-position:center implies a 50% position on both axes, I've added a height:100% on the html in fiddle to better demonstrate this, try resizing the output box vertically/horizontally to see it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/dk329q1L/1/

Comment: i should build you a monument for this, seriously i were going crazy :D tnx a lot, now just need to learn how to "setup" (?) a css xD
again, tnx a lot

Comment: Haha :D, ways of 'setting up' a css are here - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 1):

you could achive this by doing this also:

```
background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the background add:

```
document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
```

Comment: wow, it works! tnx a lot, just a little question (if possible), i see now the bg is centered horizontally, but on vertically i see the image on the bottom is it possible to center the bgs also vertically ? (look this to understand better :D http://i.imgur.com/qoz58Yq.png ) (and here to see the code applyed : http://animevid.altervista.org/NuovoFile.html )

Comment: It should center it both ways with that already, try to add `document.body.style.height = "100%";`

Comment: tnx for your reply, i'll try it :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set margin auto in this case ,but you have to specify   width
you have   to assign id  :

```
  {
        width:100px;
     }   margin: auto;
```

Comment: tnx a lot, i'll try also your way :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `background-position` for your element, add this line to your code:

```
document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center top";
```

The value `center top` means that the image will be placed `center` in horizontal, and will be placed at `top` in vertical.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3c8d91f0/1/).

The below image shows other values you can use for `background-position`:

[image: background-position]